# Is there any research on zonal OCR / field level ORC / template OCR?

Tags: terminology, ocr

I've recently found the term "Zonal OCR": ([source 1](https://www.chronoscan.org/features_zonal_ocr.asp), [2](https://www.efilecabinet.com/zonal-ocr/), [3](https://www.openkm.com/old/en/openkm-zone-ocr.html), [4](https://www.logicaldoc.com/software-features/zonal-ocr)). It seems to be essentially OCR, but restricted to relevant parts of the document.

The interesting task about which I want to learn more is how to find those zones automatically. How is this called? Is this a field of research? Could you point me to a publication so that I can start learning about this topic?

("Field Level recognition" and "Template OCR" seems to be a synonym for zonal OCR)

### What I found

- [Dynamic Programming Approach to Template-based OCR](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.07933.pdf), but they don't reference anything OCR related